# Перегрузка индексации

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Есть класс:

```
class A
{
   public:
     int& operator [] (int a)
     {
        return x.at(a);
     }
     int operator [] (int a) const
     {
        return x.at(a);
     }
   private:
     vector<int> x;
};
```

Так как реализация обеих перегрузок одинаковая, хочу объединить их в шаблон. Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: у оператора [] и функции at разная "идеология". [] не возвращает исключений, если индекс за пределами, а вот at - возвращает.

Поэтому, использование at внутри [] нарушает соглашения.

Comment: @KoVadim Я могу в реализации [] написать всё что угодно, какие соглашения это нарушает?

Comment: @KoVadim Это соглашение на уровне стандартной либы, не?

Comment: В стандарте так принято для всех контейнеров. Вы можете нарушать это соглашение, но сторонние разработчики, которые будут пользоваться Вашим кодом, могут ожидать стандартного поведения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет.

Хоть эти два метода содержат одинаковый текст, но они абсолютно разные: один работает на константном объекте и возвращает целое число, вызывая константный метод at; другой работает на неконстантном объекте, возвращает ссылку из неконстантного метода at. В целом, у них разные сигнатуры и разная реализация.

К слову, обычно перегрузки делают так:

```
int& operator [] (int a)
const int& operator [] (int a) const
```

Шаблоны предполагают, что класс обобщается по некоторому параметру-типу (или значению). Здесь они вообще не при чём. Впрочем, если вы хотите, чтобы ваш класс поддерживал не только `int`, то можно сделать шаблон:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
   public:
     T& operator [] (int a)
     {
        return x.at(a);
     }
     const T& operator [] (int a) const
     {
        return x.at(a);
     }
   private:
     vector<T> x;
};
```

Comment: В чём разница между возвращаемым значением `int` и `const int&` в данном случае?

Comment: @Georgiy В данном — никакого. А если переписывать на шаблон, то переписывать меньше. Ну и сигнатура с векторовским at совпадёт. Вкусовщина. :)

Comment: А в общем случае что лучше использовать?

Comment: @Georgiy В случае шаблона — константную ссылку. Тогда (гарантированно) не будет копирования. Для сложных объектов это имеет значение. В общем, логика простая: когда сомневаешься, смотри стандартную либу, там всё по уму. :)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос снят